# How to make range of labels in javascript graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph

I want to make range of labels like 90 to 1.  How I can do it insted of typeing '90',89','88',....
Please help. Should I use ForEach loop or something else or there is some function like range(1-90)?

```
 $.getJSON("/administration/statistics/datasource/grafpobrojuuplata90dana.json", function (data) {
    zbrojevi = data.zbrojevi;
    var result = Object.values(zbrojevi);
    console.log(result);
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grafpobrojuuplata90dana').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',
        axisX:{
          scaleBreaks: {
                autoCalculate: true
            }
        },
        toolTip: {
            shared: true
        },
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['90','89','88','87','86','85','84','83','82','81','80','79','78','77','76','75','74','73','72','71','70','69','68','67','66','65','64','63','62','61','60','59','58','57','56','55','54','53','52','51','50','49','48','47','46','45','44','43','42','41','40','39','38','37','36','35','34','33','32','31','30','29', '28', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23','22','21','20','19','18','17','16','15','14','13','12','11','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1','danas'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Graf po broju uplata 90 dana',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(51, 153, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
                data: result


            }]
        },


    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var label = [];
for (var j = 90; j >= 1; j--) {
  label.push(j);
}
console.log(label);
```